# inner div height css

Tags: html, css

I have the container that have 100% height and its work great

I want the Client Content will be 80%
I want it to be like this

[Example http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/2822/exmapler.png](http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/2822/exmapler.png)

Here is my page HTML and CSS

CSS

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

#container
{
    min-height: 99%;
    border-color: #36A9E9;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: ThreeDFace;
}
* html #container
{
    height: 100%;
}
#ClientContent
{
    min-height: 80%;
    border-color: #36A9E9;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: ThreeDFace;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<form id="container" runat="server">

<div id="ClientContent">

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

please suggest any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TqxHq/2/)

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
#container
{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 99%;
    border-color: #36A9E9;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: ThreeDFace;
}
* html #container
{
    height: 100%;
}
#ClientContent
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 80%;
    border-color: #36A9E9;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 99.6%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: ThreeDFace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `#Clientcontent {height:80%}`

Comment: what browser are you having this issue with?

Comment: You can absolute `position` the div within your `#container` form like how @SwDevMan81 has done it.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to put the vertical align to top and it should be ok. Put it on the #ClientContent. I'm not sure if that is what really is missing. Try to add max-height:80% aswell. Like this:

```
#ClientContent
{
max-height:80%;
vertical-align:top;
min-height: 80%;
border-color: #36A9E9;
border-width: thin;
border-style: solid;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: ThreeDFace;
}
```

Comment: Your clientContent element what is it? Is it a div? a span? a p?